# ASUS Motherboard, RAID recovery

Tags: windows-8, raid

I have an ASUS Z77 motherboard and running two SSD's in RAID 1. My question is, if one drive fails, how would I even know unless I rebooted my computer and saw in the BIOS that the drive is failed/degraded?

I do keep a ghosted image of the boot/main drive. If losing the RAID 1 seems like a better idea, what could the other SSD be used for?

MB: ASUS Sabertooth Z77
SSD: 2 x Samsung 840 Pro Series 256GB
HHD: 4 x 2TB in storage pool

Answer (score 0):

> how would I even know unless I rebooted my computer and saw in the BIOS that 
>   the drive is failed/degraded?

A drive failure would also show up in other places. E.g. in the event viewer, and in disk management (yellow exclamation mark in front of the drive). Depending on how you set up the RAID you might also get a mail with a warning stating that a drive has failed.

The latter is common with HW RAID installations and on unix where you set a cron script to mail you errors.  No idea how to do that with storage spaces.)